# Rails 4, how to ask for current password in password change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, change-password

I am following this solution: [Rails 4 - Allow password change only if current password is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293379/rails-4-allow-password-change-only-if-current-password-is-correct)

But my password updates regardless if I input the correct current password or not. Here is my code:

Employee model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password, :current_password

    def self.authenticate(user, password)  
        employee = find_by_code(user)
        if employee && employee.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, employee.password_salt)  
            employee  
        end  
    end  

    validates_presence_of :current_password, if: :validate_password?, on: :update
    validate :current_password_is_correct, if: :validate_password?, on: :update

    def current_password_is_correct
        if Employee.authenticate(code, current_password) == false 
            errors.add(:current_password, "Wrong password.")
        end
    end

    def validate_password?
        !password.blank?
    end
end
```

If I change the current_password_is_correct to this it properly shows the error:

```
def current_password_is_correct
    if Employee.authenticate(code, current_password) == false || true
        errors.add(:current_password, "Wrong password.")
    end
end
```

Which makes me think that probably the password is updated before this validation is executed. How can I be sure of this, and if it is so, how can I make it execute in the correct order?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method

```
def self.authenticate(user, password)  
    employee = find_by_code(user)
    if employee && employee.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, employee.password_salt)  
        employee  
    end  
end
```

returns `nil` if it doesn't match the employee.  When you test the results of it, here:

```
def current_password_is_correct
    if Employee.authenticate(code, current_password) == false 
        errors.add(:current_password, "Wrong password.")
    end
end
```

you specifically test if the result `== false`.  `nil` does not equal `false`, and neither does an employee object, so this test will always return false, and never add the errors.  I would change this method to:

```
def current_password_is_correct
  unless Employee.authenticate(code, current_password)
    errors.add(:current_password, "Wrong password.")
  end
end
```

The "unless" case will be triggered by anything "falsy" which includes `false` or `nil`.

Comment: Also, refactor your `authenticate` method as per @jonsnow's advice as it's a bit cleaner.  Otherwise you're being caught out by the fact that an if block returns nil if it's test doesn't pass.

Comment: Thanks your advice was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

change your method like this, And check the same

```
def self.authenticate(user, password)  
    employee = find_by_code(user)
    employee && employee.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, employee.password_salt)
end
```

Comment: You nerr nothing @jonsnerr - sorry, this is a good suggestion, i just couldn't resist it.

Answer (score 0):

In Devise gem, you can use update_with_password method to ask the current password using st

Its works on rails 4 and 5.

```
def update_password
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(password_params)
    end 
end

private
def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```